# No Option To "Generate Step Definitions" In Specflow

Tags: automated-testing, bdd, specflow, acceptance-testing

I do not see the option to "generate step definitions" in Specflow.

I have installed the Specflow add-on by going to: `Tools >> Extensions And Updates`

I have also added **NUnit3** Test Adapter.

In troubleshooting, I have changed the feature file name. I thought that it will then allow me to generate new step definitions - when I right click on the feature file- I do not see any option to create step definations. I have attached a screen shot of feature file in Windows Explorer.

I have tried re-installing SpecFlow & SpecFlow.NUnit - as per [this article.](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/474)

In addition, I installed SpecRun. SpecFlow as [per this article.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683410/specflow-generate-step-definitions-missing-from-context-menu)

Also, I am using **V/Studio 2015 Community Edition.**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Right Click In The Code Editor (And Not The Solution Explorer) And The Option To "Generate Step Definitions" Is There.